# #[derive(Clone)] with a Weak generic

Tags: rust

The following code fails to compile with Rust 1.27 and nightly [(playground)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=d73e2ef1b6a08e1a09cccf4a2cfdfca6&version=nightly&mode=debug):

```
use std::rc::{Rc, Weak};

struct Bar;

#[derive(Clone)]
struct Foo<T> {
    w: Weak<T>,
}

fn main() {
    let r = Rc::new(Bar);
    let w = Rc::downgrade(&r);

    let f = Foo { w };
    let _f2 = f.clone();
}
```

The resulting error message is:

```
error[E0599]: no method named `clone` found for type `Foo<Bar>` in the current scope
  --> src/main.rs:15:17
   |
6  | struct Foo<T> {
   | ------------- method `clone` not found for this
...
15 |     let _f2 = f.clone();
   |                 ^^^^^
   |
   = note: the method `clone` exists but the following trait bounds were not satisfied:
           `Foo<Bar> : std::clone::Clone`
   = help: items from traits can only be used if the trait is implemented and in scope
   = note: the following trait defines an item `clone`, perhaps you need to implement it:
           candidate #1: `std::clone::Clone`
```

This is weird because, the `Clone` type is derived for that type, and I assume that if a `derive` does not fail, then given trait will be implemented.

Why do I get this error?

I also tried this code:

```
fn main() {
    let r = Rc::new(Bar);
    let w = Rc::downgrade(&r);
    let f = Foo { w };
    let _f2 = Clone::clone(&f);
}
```

The error message is quite curious:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `Bar: std::clone::Clone` is not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:14:15
   |
14 |     let _f2 = Clone::clone(&f);
   |               ^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `std::clone::Clone` is not implemented for `Bar`
   |
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `std::clone::Clone` for `Foo<Bar>`
   = note: required by `std::clone::Clone::clone`
```

Is that a hint that there is a bug in the implementation of `derive(Clone)`?

Changing the definition to this compiles:

```
#[derive(Clone)]
struct Foo {
    w: Weak<Bar>,
}
```

I thought that I might be missing a generic constraint on `T`, but what could it be (`T: ?Clone` makes no sense)?